# Is ATC clearance or permission required to fly helicopter routes and transitions in the Los Angeles area?

Tags: faa-regulations, air-traffic-control, helicopter, aeronautical-charts

Skyvector has Los Angeles helicopter charts [here](https://skyvector.com/?ll=33.94240879630591,-118.40806870531615&chart=201&zoom=7&fpl=3838N09012W%203845N09020W) and [here](https://skyvector.com/?ll=33.919129396721125,-117.7276735578368&chart=202&zoom=7&fpl=3838N09012W%203845N09020W).

Are pilots required to obtain ATC clearance or permission to fly helicopter routes and transitions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the FAA's [JO7210.3AA *Facility Operation and Administration*](https://www.faa.gov/regulations_policies/orders_notices/index.cfm/go/document.information/documentID/1029468) (chapter 11, section 5):

> Pilot adherence to charted helicopter routes and the recommended
>   altitudes or flight ceilings associated with them will normally be
>   voluntary. However, controllers may assign charted routes and
>   altitudes and expect or request pilot compliance with them, provided
>   such procedures are called for in specific FAA−operator Letters of
>   Agreement, or are necessitated by traffic density and/or safety
>   considerations; controllers also may restrict operations within
>   designated operating zones when requested by local law enforcement
>   officials and the restriction would not adversely affect other
>   aircraft operations.

In other words, it's mostly a voluntary thing but pilots should still be aware of them and prepared to follow them if instructed.

And you have to consider the airspace as well: large parts of some routes are in uncontrolled class G airspace, e.g. the PALISADES coastal route, west of Santa Monica. ATC doesn't control traffic in class G, so asking for permission wouldn't make sense.

Comment: @jeff0000 Oops, I added the missing chapter to the answer. Thanks for pointing that out!